# How to get a asp variable into a html input variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input, asp-classic

I'm trying to get a asp variable in a JavaScript function, I'm trying to pass the variable through this

```
<input type="hidden" id="abc" value="<% variable %>">
```

and then I get the value through

```
document.getElementById('abc').value;
```

but gives me error, is there a better way or how can I put the asp variable as the input value?

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: @Yaje it just shows this: _here to find out more about this error._, it stops showing the rest of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`<input type="hidden" id="abc" value="<%= variable %">`

UPDATE:

`<% %>` refers to a generic code block. you can still try and do something inside that block like say, `<% Response.Write(variable) %>`. It won't necessarily return something unless you tell it to.

`<%= %>` on the other hand, is a shortcut to `<% Response.Write() %>`

Comment: This is the right answer, thanks, I have another question, it doesn't give me error, but in the javascript I compare that variable with anoter one (both strings).
How can I do that since `==` isn't working?

Comment: do you compare it like this: var isSameValue = document.getElementById('abc').value == document.getElementById('someOtherField').value;

Comment: Yes, it could be that in the string I have accents like this "**é**"?

Comment: Wel sorry my bad it seems I gave the wrong value to the asp variable

Comment: How about instead of just posting code you actually explain what the `<%= %>` means and why `<% %>` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="abc" value=@variable>
```

I use asp.net core 1.1